# kettle etl how to convert to a time data type

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a table input and gets some data from a SQL Server table. One field has values of type time, e.g. 02:22:57.0000000, the destination table (table output ) is a PostgreSQL table and  has data type of time for that field. But PDI seems think the time from the source table is of type string and generates an error.

> ERROR: column "contact_time" is of type time without time zone but expression is of type character varying

I tried using select value step, but there is no time type, only date and timestamp. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Select Values** step and in the **meta-data** tab, select Type as **Timestamp** and Format as **HH:mm:ss**

This will format your string input to timestamp.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes it helped!  Thanks!
Also, make sure that your data tab has no rows. Not even empty ones.